# Is network manager incapatible with network namespace

Tags: networking, network-manager

I've appreciated the power of network namespace, like [there](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) and [there](https://schnouki.net/posts/2014/12/12/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/).

But when I try to replicate the tutorial, it doesn't work at all, and I'm pretty sure that it's because network-manager is messing with it. When I turn it down and configure the network the old-school way (/etc/nework/interfaces), it works perfectly.

Any solution to use network namespace with network-manager, which is very cool otherwise.

Comment: I'm using this project and works with network manager enabled  https://github.com/randunel/node-nns